# call to getThingShadow does not seem to execute in lambda function

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, aws-iot

I am working on a lambda alexa skill handler that integrates with a thing shadow in aws IoT. My problem is that the call below to iotData.getThingShadow does not seem to execute. None of the console messages are generated within the callback function and the object objState is not getting populated. Here is the code snippet.

```
   // get the shadow for the home-garage-door
    console.log('Getting thing shadow');

    iotData.getThingShadow(params, function(err, data) {
        console.log('Inside of getThingShadow callback');
        if (err){
            //Handle the error here
            console.log('Problem getting the thing shadow');
            console.log(err, err.stack);
            responseString = "I had trouble contacting the garage door, sorry";
        }
        else {
            console.log("Data back from shadow", JSON.stringify(data));
            payload = data.payload;
            objState = JSON.parse(payload);
        }
    });

    console.log('After getting the Shadow');
```

Below is the log entries generated when I test. Does anyone have any ideas what I may have wrong?

```
2018-01-14T22:55:15.564Z    fbdde171-f97d-11e7-bc0b-116e508011bd    Getting thing shadow
2018-01-14T22:55:16.127Z    fbdde171-f97d-11e7-bc0b-116e508011bd    After getting the Shadow
2018-01-14T22:55:16.165Z    fbdde171-f97d-11e7-bc0b-116e508011bd    objState: undefined
```

Here is the complete code.

```
/**
    Copyright 2014-2015 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of the License is located at

        http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0/

    or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
*/

/**
 *
 */

/**
 * App ID for the skill
 */
 var APP_ID = 'amzn1.ask.skill.XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'; 


/**
 * The AlexaSkill prototype and helper functions
 */
var AlexaSkill = require('./AlexaSkill');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

/**
 * GarageDoorIntentHandler is a child of AlexaSkill.
 * To read more about inheritance in JavaScript, see the link below.
 *
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance
 */
var GarageDoorIntentHandler = function () {
    AlexaSkill.call(this, APP_ID);
};

// Extend AlexaSkill
GarageDoorIntentHandler.prototype = Object.create(AlexaSkill.prototype);
GarageDoorIntentHandler.prototype.constructor = GarageDoorIntentHandler;

GarageDoorIntentHandler.prototype.eventHandlers.onSessionStarted = function (sessionStartedRequest, session) {
    console.log("GarageDoorIntentHandler onSessionStarted requestId: " + sessionStartedRequest.requestId
        + ", sessionId: " + session.sessionId);
    // any initialization logic goes here
};

GarageDoorIntentHandler.prototype.eventHandlers.onLaunch = function (launchRequest, session, response) {
    console.log("GarageDoorIntentHandler onLaunch requestId: " + launchRequest.requestId + ", sessionId: " + session.sessionId);
    var speechOutput = "Welcome to the Automated Garage door for Alexa, you can say open the garage door or close the garage door";
    var repromptText = "You can say open or close the garage door";
    response.ask(speechOutput, repromptText);
};

GarageDoorIntentHandler.prototype.eventHandlers.onSessionEnded = function (sessionEndedRequest, session) {
    console.log("GarageDoorIntentHandler onSessionEnded requestId: " + sessionEndedRequest.requestId
        + ", sessionId: " + session.sessionId);
    // any cleanup logic goes here
};

GarageDoorIntentHandler.prototype.intentHandlers = {

    // register custom intent handlers
    "moveDoorIntent": function (intent, session, response) {

        var responseString = ''; 
        var payload = {};
        var objState;

        var desiredDoorState = intent.slots.direction.value;

        var iotData = new AWS.IotData({endpoint: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"});

        console.log('iotData: ' + JSON.stringify(iotData));

        var params = { "thingName" : "<My Thing Name Was Removed for Posting>" };


        console.log('Intent: ' + JSON.stringify(intent));

        // get the shadow for the home-garage-door
        console.log('Getting thing shadow');

        iotData.getThingShadow(params, function(err, data) {
            console.log('Inside of getThingShadow callback');
            if (err){
                //Handle the error here
                console.log('Problem getting the thing shadow');
                console.log(err, err.stack);
                responseString = "I had trouble contacting the garage door, sorry";
            }
            else {
                console.log("Data back from shadow", JSON.stringify(data));
                payload = data.payload;
                objState = JSON.parse(payload);
            }
        });

        console.log('After getting the Shadow');

        switch(desiredDoorState.toUpperCase()) {
            case 'OPEN':
                console.log('objState: ' + JSON.stringify(objState));
                switch (objState.state.reported.status.toUpperCase()) {
                    case 'OPEN': 
                        responseString = "I checked and the door is already open"; 
                        break;
                    case 'CLOSED':
                        responseString = "Ok, I am closing the garage door"; 
                        params.payload = buildObjectState('desired', 'doorActivated', true, 'string');
                        iotData.updateThingShadow(params, function(err, data) {
                            if (err){
                                //Handle the error here
                                console.log(err, err.stack);
                                responseString = "I had trouble doing that, sorry";
                            }
                            else {
                                responseString = "Ok, I opened the garage door";
                                console.log("Data back from shadow", data);
                            }
                        });
                }
                break;
            case 'CLOSE':
                break;
            default: 

        } // switch

        response.tellWithCard(responseString, "Open or Close the Garage Door", responseString);
    },

    "getDoorStateIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
        response.tellWithCard("You can say hello to me!", "You can say hello to me!");
    }
};


/**
*   Helper function to build the state object for the shadow document
**/

function buildObjectState (section, key, value, format) {

    var objState =  {state: {}};

    objState.state[section] = {};
    objState.state[section][key] = value;


    if (format === 'object') {
        return objState;
    } else if (format === 'string') {
        return JSON.stringify(objState);
    } else return; 

}

// Create the handler that responds to the Alexa Request.
exports.handler = function (event, context) {

    console.log('received an event'); 
    // Create an instance of the garageDoorIntentHandler.
    var garageDoorIntentHandler = new GarageDoorIntentHandler();
    garageDoorIntentHandler.execute(event, context);
};
```

Comment: Can you post the entire code? You did not show the `console.log()` line that produces `objState: undefined`.

Comment: thanks for taking a look. I added the complete code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, code execution continues on to the next line without waiting for async function calls to finish. The error in your code is because you accessed `objState` when it doesn't have a value yet.

See the comments below to understand it better.

```
// This is called BEFORE iotData.getThingShadow()
console.log('Getting thing shadow');

iotData.getThingShadow(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log('Inside of getThingShadow callback');
    if (err) {
        //Handle the error here
        console.log('Problem getting the thing shadow');
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        responseString = "I had trouble contacting the garage door, sorry";
    } else {
        console.log("Data back from shadow", JSON.stringify(data));
        payload = data.payload;
        // This is populated AFTER iotData.getThingShadow() finishes
        objState = JSON.parse(payload);
        // This is where you put the code that you want to happen AFTER 
        // iotData.getThingShadow() finishes.
        console.log(objState)
    }
});

// This will execute without waiting for iotData.getThingShadow() to finish
console.log('After getting the Shadow');

// This will be undefined since iotData.getThingShadow() did NOT return 
// yet and objState has NOT been populated
console.log(objState)
```

So, to fix it, move the code that you want to happen AFTER iotData.getThingShadow() FINISHES inside the callback function.

Comment: That makes total sense. I am still trying to get used to that. I will refactor and follow up on this post accordingly. If I would have trapped the access to objState, I would have seen the log entries come through asynchronously, I imagine.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your IOT object is nested in an Intent.

I would move your IoT shadows and initializing into their own

```
/Initialize Up Top of Script
AWS.config.region = process.env.IOT_REGION;
var IOT_Data = new AWS.IotData({endpoint: process.env.IOT_ENDPOINT});
var IOT_Thing = process.env.IOT_THING_NAME;
```

Then I use a helper function:

```
function getShadow(dataObj){
    IOT_Data.getThingShadow(dataObj, function (err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    })
}
```

Your IOT object is now available wherever you wish. I've used this set up in multiple skills without issue.